# How to prepopulate jsf input components after the page is loaded?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces, seam

I'm trying to pre populate a `JSF` input components with a specific default value after the page is loaded. How can i achieved this?

I'm setting the submitted value of all the input fields but its not working, maybe the view is not yet initialized. I read about phase listeners but i don't know where phase i can do these.

By the way im using Seam Entity Home to bind the value of each input components.

Example:

```
 <h:inputText value="#{entityHome.instance.name}" />
```

something like this.

Is there someone who knows how to do this in JSF 1.2? Thanks. :))

Comment: what do you want to pre populate in JSF input? predefined value, submitted value or from database?

Comment: The values from Database. Im setting the default instance to its HomeEntity using setId();

Answer (score 3):

try

```
<f:metadata> 
 <f:event listener="#{backBean.method()}" type="preRenderView"/>
<f:metadata>
```

in ur method() there should be logic of retrieving data and set it in entityHome.instance.

type can be preRenderView or preRenderComponent based on your requirement, and even wrapper of `<f:metadata>` is also not required in some case, its also based on your requirement how you want to call the method.

Comment: i'm using jsf 1.2 so there is no f:event :)

Comment: have you tried `@PostConstructis` method of the constructor of your backing bean. BTW is there any specific requirements for useing jsf 1.2? use jsf 2.x.

Comment: we are still using jsf 1.2 in our project..so we cant upgrade that easily you know...:))

Comment: Even in Jsf2.0 preRenderView is probably a wrong choice for accessing database. @PostCostruct will ensure execution only while bean is initiated. Whereas preRenderEvent will invoke it every time page is loaded. Even on postbacks and reloads.

Comment: Oh i see. Then its still better to use `@PostConstruct` instead. Thank you very much for this information, it was very helpful.